# Could not locate source_path "null" with aws lambda module in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I have the following .tf file to deploy a lambda layer with terraform:

```
module "lambda_layer_pip_requirements" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"

  create_function = false
  create_layer    = true

  layer_name          = "test"
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.9"]
  runtime             = "python3.9"

  source_path = [
    {
      path             = jsonencode("./../../../aws/lambda")
      pip_requirements = true
      prefix_in_zip    = "python"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run terraform apply I get this error:

```
Error Message: Could not locate source_path "null".
```

I have tried changing the path value in sourcepath with this values:

- "./../../../aws/lambda"
- jsonencode("./../../../aws/lambda")
- "/home/user/workspace/project/aws/lambda/requirements.txt"
- "${path.module}/../../../aws/lambda"

Always getting the same error. The complete error is:

```
 Error: invalid value for name (must match [\w+=,.@-])
│
│   with module.lambda.aws_iam_role.lambda[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/lambda/iam.tf line 97, in resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda":
│   97:   name                  = local.role_name
│
╵
╷
│ Error: invalid value for name (must match [\w+=,.@-])
│
│   with module.lambda.aws_iam_policy.logs[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/lambda/iam.tf line 136, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "logs":
│  136:   name   = "${local.policy_name}-logs"
│
╵
╷
│ Error: External Program Execution Failed
│
│   with module.lambda.data.external.archive_prepare[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/lambda/package.tf line 10, in data "external" "archive_prepare":
│   10:   program = [local.python, "${path.module}/package.py", "prepare"]
│
│ The data source received an unexpected error while attempting to execute the program.
│
│ Program: /home/user/.pyenv/shims/python3
│ Error Message: Could not locate source_path "null".  Paths are relative to directory where `terraform plan` is being
│ run ("/home/user/workspace/project/terraform/environments/dev")
│
│ State: exit status 1
```

My project structure is this:

```
.
├── aws
│   ├── emr
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── orm.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── p1.py
│   │   ├── bootstrap.sh
│   │   ├── p2.py
│   │   ├── config.yml
│   │   ├── nrm.py
│   │   ├── orm.py
│   │   ├── p3.py
│   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   │   └── utils.py
│   └── lambda
│       ├── config.yml
│       ├── emr.json
│       ├── requirements.txt
│       └── runp4.py
├── deployment
│   └── deploy.sh
└── terraform
    └── environments
        ├── dev
        │   ├── builds
        │   │   ├── 75b2f7d8ec34af35b0edf7097eab15077f4ee2919bfa79f66ef8bcb336231c46.plan.json
        │   │   ├── 84abeb56ece748bb85ef6ff0a09a345a50717b2cb10bea3f148e74b38dac204e.plan.json
        │   │   └── 9aa81e58a8cc59e5bff005fe20508662c2de64c21c32b2a1c08171f0c827b00f.plan.json
        │   ├── emr.tf
        │   ├── iam.tf
        │   ├── lambda.tf
        │   ├── locals.tf
        │   ├── main.tf
        │   ├── module.tf
        │   └── provider.tf
        └── prod
```

I run terraform apply inside terraform/environments/dev directory.

How can I solve this error and deploy de lambda layer to AWS?

Edit:

Setting `export TF_LAMBDA_PACKAGE_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG3` I got this error:

```
╷
│ Error: External Program Execution Failed
│
│   with module.lambda.data.external.archive_prepare[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/lambda/package.tf line 10, in data "external" "archive_prepare":
│   10:   program = [local.python, "${path.module}/package.py", "prepare"]
│
│ The data source received an unexpected error while attempting to execute the program.
│
│ Program: /home/user/.pyenv/shims/python3
│ Error Message: [13253] prepare: {'artifacts_dir': 'builds', 'docker': '', 'hash_extra': '', 'hash_extra_paths': '[]',
│ 'paths':
│ '{"cwd":"/home/user/workspace/project/terraform/environments/dev","module":".terraform/modules/lambda","root":"."}',
│ 'recreate_missing_package': 'true', 'runtime': '', 'source_path': 'null'}
│ [13253] prepare: QUERY: {
│   "artifacts_dir": "builds",
│   "docker": "",
│   "hash_extra": "",
│   "hash_extra_paths": "[]",
│   "paths": "{\"cwd\":\"/home/user/workspace/project/terraform/environments/dev\",\"module\":\".terraform/modules/lambda\",\"root\":\".\"}",
│   "recreate_missing_package": "true",
│   "runtime": "",
│   "source_path": "null"
│ }
│ Could not locate source_path "null".  Paths are relative to directory where `terraform plan` is being run
│ ("/home/user/workspace/project/terraform/environments/dev")
│
│ State: exit status 1
╵
```

Comment: How about `path = "${path.root}/../../../aws/lambda"`? Also, any reason to use `jsonencode` for this?

Comment: With "${path.root}/../../../aws/lambda" I get the same error. I saw some people using jsonencode here: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/issues/215

Comment: The error is actually coming from the Python helper script: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/master/package.py#L766. Are you sure that directory exists?

Comment: Yes, the folder exists and also the requirementstxt file

Comment: I think it actually might be related to the previous error that is there. Which module version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.12.1, but i'm not sure. How can I check module version?

Comment: There should be a file called `modules.json` inside of the `.terrafarorm` directory.

Comment: Confirmed, module version is 4.12.1. Changind source_path to jsonencode("${path.module}/../../../aws/lambda") show a different error:

Error Message: Could not locate source_path ""./../../../aws/lambda"".

Comment: Are you using terragrunt? I see no reason to use `jsonencode` unless you are using terragrunt.

Comment: No, just using terraform.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the directory that you have and commands that you use to run the TF exactly, and **full** TF code.

Comment: @Marcin I have edited the question with the required info.

Comment: Hello, Can you "export TF_LAMBDA_PACKAGE_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG3", run the plan again and display the result please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the exception:

```
│ The data source received an unexpected error while attempting to execute the program.
│
│ Program: /home/user/.pyenv/shims/python3
│ Error Message: Could not locate source_path "null".  Paths are relative to directory where `terraform plan` is being
│ run ("/home/user/workspace/project/terraform/environments/dev")
```

And from the directory tree provided and that the desired source path required, based upon that tree is `./aws/lambda`, the relative path required, working back from where terraform plan is being run should be: `../../../aws/lambda`

This is due to the following, based upon working back from the path: `/home/user/workspace/project/terraform/environments/dev`

`..` will return you to `/home/user/workspace/project/terraform/environments`

`../..` will return you to `/home/user/workspace/project/terraform`

`../../..` will return you to `/home/user/workspace/project`

then work your way from there into the directory required, so in your case as noted above, your terraform code should be:

```
module "lambda_layer_pip_requirements" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"

  create_function = false
  create_layer    = true

  layer_name          = "test"
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.9"]
  runtime             = "python3.9"

  source_path = [
    {
      path             = "../../../aws/lambda"
      pip_requirements = true
      prefix_in_zip    = "python"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This returns the same result. I have tried with many options in the path,always with the same result.

Comment: What do you want in the lambda layer ? all 4 files ? if all 4 files, try the following: update the  prefix_in_zip value to "."

Comment: No, I want the libraries listed in the requirements.txt. I have tried setting "." in prefix_in_zip with the same result.

Comment: OK - I understand your prefix option, now in regards to pip install etc. Let's try the value for prefix_in_zip to be "./python" with the path in my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Trying with "/python" shows the same error.

Comment: @Shadowtrooper Actually, just thought that the 'aws' sub directory at the same directory area as the 'terraform' sub directory. So lets try ```path = "../../aws/lambda"```. Aassuming that main.tf file is inside terraform/environments/dev dir which contains the module.lambda_layer_pip_requirements block.

Comment: Yes, it's solved. The error was that I have the same module with same name n other .tf file but empty. Thanks for your help!!!